# JsonDecode FormatException?

Tags: flutter

Could someone help me find out why, the flutter is saying that my json:

> =FormatException: Unexpected character: "variable1 : nul "

already checked my json file, and it is coming right, however when giving Json decode, this problem is occurring. this its the json example, its a list with like 1000 itens.

```
[
{
    "id":2,
    "first_name":"NRD",
    "phone":"",
    "description":"",
    "created_at":"2020-12-22 08:02:20",
    "aveg":112,
    "updated_at":"2020-12-22 08:02:20",
    "long":1,
    "lat":"1",
    "link":"localhost:8000",
    "temperature_id":1,
    "email":"sem@email.com",
    "user":"null"
},
]
```

Comment: Could you please share the json?

Comment: you have to post your code and JSON data in order to get a good answer.

Comment: !already edit with the json